# Sylvester's determinant for matrix of grassman variables.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume one has two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ containing only anticommuting grassmann variables. The task is to find the following product:
$$\det(I-AB)\det(I-BA).$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Grassmann variables have the following property:
$$xy = -yx\quad\text{ and }\quad x^2 = 0.$$

Thank you for your attention.